# Mercator projection that shrinks toward pole

Tags: coordinate-system

I've noticed that lots of map viewer (especially those nautical chart viewer) will shrink a mercator projected chart while panning towards poles.

Is this some compensation for mercator distortion?

Is this a dedicated projection?

How to implement that?

Comment: you shouldn't crosspost in all possible sites/mailing list's... it is not a correct approach: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680467/mercator-projection-shrink-toward-pole) & [2](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Mercator-projection-that-shrinks-toward-pole-td5031876.html)

Comment: Formulas for the scale of a Mercator projection are given in the answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/40659.  Concerning your last question, what platform do you intend to use for the implementation?

Comment: Here is a little puzzle that will illustrate what google mercator does. [Mercator puzzle](https://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/puzzledrag.html?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=mdr-general)

Comment: I'm thinking that the shrink is to make the scale always the same along latitude, so , say (px, py) is normally projected coordinate, to get it shrinked, use (x, y) = (px*cos(lat), py*cos(lat))

Comment: If the Mercator implementation supports a standard parallel, they may be changing it to match the screen's central latitude. That will "shrink" a Mercator-based map.

Comment: Mercator is a projection that is not conserving areas. As Brad's link shows, that can have a great impact on the visualisation.